# IntelliJ IDEA - different team members on mac/PC

Tags: git, intellij-idea

At the moment we are using IntelliJ IDEA with two developers who are both using the PC Version of IntelliJ IDEA 10.5 .

One of us is moving to a Mac because iOS Development is an issue.

We have `.ipr` files setup each locally, for example in `d:\ideaproject\projectroot`.

The project consists of several modules who have their `.iml` file on a network drive, for example in:

```
k:\ideaprojects\project\module1.iml
k:\ideaprojects\project\module2.iml
```

We both have the same drive letters, so this works flawless.

When we want to setup the Mac exactly the same, but this is not possible because in the `.iml` files there are references to `k:\` and other network drive letters.  The Mac does not know drive letters, of course.

How can we setup in a way we all can work in one project? We thought of setting up git, but in the IDEA documentation they are mentioning that the `.iml` file has to be in the CVS. So the same problem exists.  The documentation states:

> Since *.iws file stores your personal preferences, it should not be placed under version control. On the contrary, the project and module files (*.ipr and *.iml) store project-wide settings, and should be shared.

Can anyone give us an idea how to setup a team project with team members on different platforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use path variables, see http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/paths-and-path-variables.html for details.

Answer (score 3):

**Never** share code with a network-drive. Share it always with your version-control software.

Make all paths relative. If it is a java-project use a dependency-management tool like maven. All developers have to create a local project based on the maven dependencies.

If you work with the same code ensure you use unicode file encoding, otherwise you may have *fun* with your sources.

I don't think you can build iOS apps with IntelliJ, so why do you want to get in trouble?

Answer (score 0):

Just put all of your project files (*.ipr, *.iml) in version control. Have your version control system ignore *.iws. Done.

Newer versions of IntelliJ uses directory based project settings in the .idea folder (since like IntelliJ 9 I think). Same thing applies, just put that directory in version control. You can set ignore on workspace.xml.